# How to impose predictive commoning on gcc to perform a computation reusing

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization

According to an [old slide](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~amaral/cascon/CDP04/slides/tal.pdf#page=8) about `predictive commoning`, one can say that

[test1.cpp](https://godbolt.org/z/ojGPqs)

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++)
    f[i]= a[i]*exp(i+1)+a[i+1]*exp(i+2);
```

is equivalent to

[test2.cpp](https://godbolt.org/z/mb6lB9)

```
double p0=a[0]*exp(1);
int i;
for (i=0; i < n-n%2; i+=2)
{
    double p1=a[i+1]*exp(i+2);
    f[i] = p0+p1;
    p0=a[i+2]*exp(i+3);
    f[i+1] = p1+p0;
}
for (; i < n; i++)
    f[i] = a[i]*exp(i+1)+a[i+1]*exp(i+2);
```

except for the second code is more optimized ([Benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/Dji3SetSdIYkBGZbvy_lFL9GPCo)).

I have tested `gcc` with the highest optimization level `-O3` and yet I cannot see `gcc` performing such optimization.

(Even worse these two example [A](https://godbolt.org/z/AOFyBh) and [B](https://godbolt.org/z/wQzhFs))

How can I force `gcc` to perform such an optimization?

Comment: "except for the second code is more optimized" --> what is your posted evidence that the 2nd is more optimized?  Have you tested any code, with highest optimization settings, to see which performs faster?  Too often, such complication prevents a complier from doing its optimization well.

Comment: @chux, is there any optimization level higher than the `-O3` that I set?

Comment: Yes I now see "tested gcc with the highest optimization level -O3".  Still how does code compare in performance using your 2 approaches?

Comment: @chux, How about [this benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/0JlY0_usV6Nu7zsSBoDcZdTO8LQ)?

Comment: @chux, from assembly, it is clear that the first code counts `i` one by one via `add     rbx, 1` while the second one does it this way `add     rbx, 2`.

Comment: A concern to your tests is that code accesses elements outside `a[n]` with `a[i+1]`.  Perhaps `double a[N]` should be `double a[N+1]`?  This is UB - best to clean that up first.

Comment: @chux, Thanks. I updated the codes and the benchmark.

Comment: The 2nd code looks like a convoluted way to avoid calling the expensive `exp()` half as often as in the first.  I suspect that is the key savings.  I've rolled a quick #3 for your consideration `void calc3(const double * restrict a, double * restrict f, int n) {
  double p0 = a[0] * exp(0 + 1);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    double p1 = a[i + 1] * exp(i + 2);
    f[i] = p0 + p1;
    p0 = p1;
  }
}
`  Of course this does not address "force gcc to perform such an optimization", yet with less complications, perhaps gcc can run this even faster.  Good luck.

Comment: @chux, Although it is not an answer, but that's a nice [benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/GlZWFdkKHoYD6MvyGjmLturFmzY) from your code.

Comment: I see you took out `restrict`.  Does not your compiler handle that?  `restrict` does allow some optimizations that are otherwise not allowed - possibly including the ones you seek here.

Comment: Further, `restrict`, simplistically speaking says `a[], f[]` do not overlap.  For if `a[], f[]` did overlap, your `calc1()` and `calc2()` are not equivalent code.  Of course the compiler cannot make that substitution/optimization you seek as it is different functionality.   Consider trying your tests employing `restrict` on `a[]` and `f[]`.

Comment: @chux, this online benchmark is for `C++`. It does no support `restrict` keyword. Apparently, restrict does not help (for method 1) according to the [assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/Qlzcpt).

Comment: Since `calc1()` and `calc2()` are _not_ always equivalent, the benchmark is of reduced value.  Looks like you need to 1) code equivalent C code and 2) benchmark _somehow_.  Good luck again.

Comment: @chux, I do not understand why you say `calc1` and `calc2` are not equivalent.

Comment: `f[i]= a[i]*exp(i+1)+a[i+1]*exp(i+2);` reads `a[]` elements for what they are _now_. With  `p1=a[i+1]*exp(i+2);
f[i] = p0+p1;
p0=a[i+2]*exp(i+3);
f[i+1] = p1+p0;`, `f[i+1] = p1+p0` is based on what `p1` was before the `f[i] = p0+p1;`.  When `f[i]` and `a[i+1]` are the same memory, `p1` should reflect what `a[i+1]` is now, not before `f[i] = ...` to achieve the same functionality.  Even if such overlap is non-sensible, the compiler cannot assume `a,f` do not overlap in some way, not without `restrict`.

Comment: It can even gets a bit uglier.  Although the compiler may "understand" `exp()`, had the function been your `atrak_exp()`, then the compiler, without `restrict` on `a`, cannot assume `a[]` did not change _somehow_ due to the  `atrak_exp()` call.  The falsify in the "predictive" part of your old slide assumes stable values in `a[]`, even though `f[]` is changing and `exp()` is called.  For your optimization to possible occur, let alone _force_, the compiler needs to make that assumption too, even via `restrict a` or _something_ else - unknown to me.

Comment: ... had `a[], f[]` been declared as arrays within the function, rather than `double *` pointers, then the complier can "know" `a,f` do not overlap nor are affected by calling `exp()` - without `restrict`.  Yet the old slide says "Accessing multiple consecutive array elements in a loop", yet your code does not use arrays, but pointers.  And pointers can point to overlapping memory.

Comment: @atrak: While C++ does not officially have `restrict`, most C++ compilers have some way to express it.  In the case of GCC, it's `__restrict__`.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found where any optimization level turns on `-fpredictive-commoning`. It looks like you have to turn it on manually.

Comment: Just search through the manpage, it is clearly listed under -O3.